# How can I extend my class from a nested in another generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new to C# (I am a Java developer) and have a question about generics. I have a generic class with nested classes:

```
public class FlowChartBuilder<TEntity, TLink> 
    where TEntity : FlowChartBuilder<TEntity, TLink>.Entity
    where TLink : FlowChartBuilder<TEntity, TLink>.Link
{
    public abstract class Link { }
    public abstract class Entity { }
}
```

The next I try to extends these classes:

```
public class ChartEntity<T>: FlowChartBuilder<ChartEntity<T>, ChartLink>.Entity
{
}

public class ChartEntity<T>: FlowChartBuilder<ChartEntity<T>, ChartLink<ChartEntity<T>>>.Entity
{
}
```

But I get an error:

> "TEntity" type can't be used like a parameter of "TEntity" type in the
>   universal type or method "FlowChartBuilder". There isn't
>   a transformation-packaging or a transformation of a type parameter from the "TEntity"
>   to the "PM.Utils.Diagram.FlowChartBuilder>.Entity".

How to write it correct?

Comment: would be cool if you could post your error in english

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't notice. I translated it already.

Comment: I think this a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566701/nested-class-that-inherits-from-its-generic-parent-class may be you will find your answer in it. It tells to replace inheritance with encaspulation.

Comment: Why nest the classes if you're just going to make them public? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7984625/302918

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo, Thank you very much! It's that I needed.

Comment: @juharr, I need it to hide a realization of some parts of classes but to it still was available in my generic class. I just removed class bodies.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Use Composition over inheritance instead.

Check here for a workaround [Nested class that inherits from its generic parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566701/nested-class-that-inherits-from-its-generic-parent-class)

Comment: Sorry, I got a jerk on. It doesn't suit in my case. Or I bad got it.

Comment: Could you provide the use case? You won't be able to inherit those class so please tell us why you wanted to do this in the first place.

Comment: To I could have an access to private members of these nested classes. Maybe, C# has some another way, just I don't know.

Comment: private member are "private". There is no way to access any data inside it.

Comment: Waah, guy, sorry) You're right, of course. Inner class has access to an outer (in Java, I didn't check it in C#). I need a rest already

Comment: But if I already wrote this. I still want to understand how to build so class hierarchy or equals.